# Will HTML5 replace silverlight?

Tags: html, silverlight

A while ago I read a news [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-our-strategy-with-silverlight-has-shifted/7834), that **Microsoft changed its strategy for silverlight and will replace it with HTML5**.

As it is a controversial discussion, some guys from Microsoft and other corporation wrote about it and some agreed and some don't?

As it is important to be aware of near future of tools that you are using, what do you think, Will Microsoft replace Silverlight with HTML5 or not?

I myself believe that **it will happen in 2012**, the time that HTML5 released completely, and Microsoft are releasing **VS2012**.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know if that's true but I hope it is. Although I haven't developed with Silverlight, I know it requires the client to install software. HTML 5, which I'm so far pretty excited about, should become much more standardized and readily available over time.

Comment: @Eric, You mean that I had to ask it in StackExchange? How to move it to stackExchange?

Comment: sometimes moderators move them, but you can always post a new one there. I don't know if its possible to move it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the future of web development: HTML5 or Silverlight(or other RIA framework)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231484/which-is-the-future-of-web-development-html5-or-silverlightor-other-ria-framewo)

Comment: I voted close as subjective. There's no problem domain context given to the question to frame which technology is more suitable for the (unknown) scenario, so "duplicate of" would be difficult to select accurately.

Comment: Don't think I'll care about Silverlight at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's intention here has been answered clearly and in fair detail by Mike Taulty.

[Silverlight *versus* HTML5? Really?](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/11/01/silverlight-versus-html5-really.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

The short and sweet takeaway is both have their respective places for the forseeable future as do other technologies discussed.